# laravel 5.2 cant pass variable to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a very simple controller and view. But for some reason I am unable to pass a variable to my view. Note that `echo $project->title` inside the router works.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $project = \App\Projects::find(1);
        return view('home', $project);
    }
```

}

View:

```
        <div class="panel-body">
            You are logged in!
            {{ $project->title }}
        </div>
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error:

> ErrorException in b605b028d5285b79f4e0043cf14415de5dddcae6.php line
>   10: Undefined variable: project (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webcast_module\resources\views\home.blade.php)
>
> in b605b028d5285b79f4e0043cf14415de5dddcae6.php line 10 at
>   CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in
>   PhpEngine.php line 44 at
>   PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\webcast_module\storage\framework\views/b605b028d5285b79f4e0043cf14415de5dddcae6.php',
>   array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application),
>   'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'eerste
>   project', 'description' => 'merijn')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59 at
>   CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\webcast_module\resources\views/home.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application),
>   'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'eerste
>   project', 'description' => 'merijn')) in View.php line 149 at
>   View->getContents() in View.php line 120 at View->renderContents() in
>   View.php line 85 at View->render() in Response.php line 53 at
>   Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201 at
>   Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1085 at
>   Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in
>   ControllerDispatcher.php line 95 at
>   ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   52 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Authenticate.php line 28 at Authenticate->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate),
>   'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
>   line 32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php
>   line 96 at
>   ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(HomeController),
>   object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php
>   line 54 at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route),
>   object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', 'index') in
>   Route.php line 174 at Route->runController(object(Request)) in
>   Route.php line 140 at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line
>   724 at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   52 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64 at
>   VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49 at
>   ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   StartSession.php line 62 at StartSession->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession),
>   'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
>   line 32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37 at
>   AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse),
>   'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
>   line 32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   EncryptCookies.php line 59 at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies),
>   'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
>   line 32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726 at
>   Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in
>   Router.php line 699 at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in
>   Router.php line 675 at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
>   line 246 at
>   Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   52 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44 at
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132 at
>   Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line
>   99 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

Comment: can you tried  return view('home', ['project' => $project]);  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: you can use **compact()**. return view('home', compact('project'));.hope it will help. :) :)

Comment: What would be better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data sent to the view needs to be an associative array. Use this instead:

```
return view('home', ['project' => $project]);
```

Answer (score 5):

replace:

```
return view('home', $project);
```

with either compact() method:

```
return view('home', compact('project'));
```

or with() method:

```
return view('home')->with('project', $project);
```

By doing this, your variable gets passed to your view as an array where the key in the array is the name of the variable and the value of that key is the variable itself.

Comment: I know its a bit late but in what case would you choose which?

Comment: @Merijndk The result is the same, `with()` is a method provided by Laravel, `compact()` is provided by PHP